# Add multiple nodes to Jenkins master

Tags: jenkins

I have around 100 `linux` servers that need to be added to a `Jenkins` master. The situation here is I need to add them by `Copy Existing Node` and the Jenkins master should not be shutdown/restart.

I don't want to do it manually for a hundred times. Is there any automation way to handle such request. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could script this (self-automate). The Jenkins agent configuration files are located in the **nodes** subdirectory in the Jenkins home directory. You'd create a sub-directory for each node and inside that put a **config.xml** file for that nodes configuration. I recommend that you shutdown your Jenkins server while doing this, we've observed Jenkins deleting things when doing this while it is running. Use an existing agent's **config.xml** file for a template. Assuming all of your servers are configured the same, you need only update the **name** and **host** tags, which can be automated using **sed**.

**Update with zero-downtime:**
CloudBees has a [support article](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/115003896171-Creating-node-with-Rest-API-and-ManuallyTrustedKeyVerificationStrategy) for creating a node using the Rest API. If you'd prefer to use the Jenkins CLI, here's an [example shell](https://gist.github.com/sergeyhush/4e892837cf5c31c3d242) script. Neither of these approaches will require restarting Jenkins.

Comment: Yes, I have also tried your solution, but the problem is that the Jenkins instance cannot be down or restarted :(.

Comment: @user3530769 Please update your question with this and any other requirements.